# http://mirror.centos.org/centos/5/os/i386/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] HTTP Error 404: Not Found

Tags: linux, centos5

in my centos 5.9 I tried to `yum check-update`

but I faced this error `http://mirror.centos.org/centos/5/os/i386/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] HTTP Error 404: Not Found`

please help me

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

CentOS 5 has reached its End-of-Life. CentOS 5 has been released in 2007 and maintenance updates were only available until 31 March 2017 (10 years!). Consider upgrading your system as soon as possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can test this in your browser as it just a regular HTTP URL.

CentOS 5 is now end of life and is now in maintenance so all repos have been removed from the main repositories.

It's in your interest to migrate to a new version. This will require a new server or virtual machine or a rebuild of your existing one.